# How to allow null values on Orchard SchemaBuilder?

Tags: orchardcms, database-migration

I'm trying to add a new column to ProjectRecord table and i want to allow null values,
Code:

> SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("ProjectRecord", table => table.AddColumn("Related", DbType.Int32));

Thanks.

Krbnr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.AddColumn<int>("Related", c => c.Nullable())
```